# How to optimize a very old patterned iOS app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6-Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have an old iOS application which is compatible for iPhone 5S(up to 5S). It was built by using regular xibs not even storyboard and not used any auto-layout concepts(auto-layouts option is also not checked for the xib), Now i placed relative splash screens for iPhone 6 and 6-plus to update the compatibility for rest of two devices and the user interface looking terrible now. Is there any simple way to update the project to compatible for iPhone 6 and 6-Plus, i mean to adjust the UI even after placing the relative splash screens for iPhone 6 and 6-plus(Without slash screens the app is working fine in iPhone 6 and 6-plus but client want to see their app in the Appstore must prompt like "This app is optimized for iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus.").
Don't think i am a stupid asking for a simple solution for this, but what to do i have 50+ xibs are there in that application so suggest me which one is better and easiest way to update the project compatibility. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: If all the layout is performed in XIBs (not in code with hardcoded values), then I think it shouldn't take a very long time to switch to autolayout manually. Just add constraints to all the XIBs. I believe, it can be done in 1-2 days even for 50 XIBs. Unfortunately, I don't know any better way. Let's hope someone else will show up.

Comment: There are no other ways but the hard way, I'm sorry :)

Comment: @FreeNickname thanks for your quick response. But i have few screens where i need to load dynamic views in the scroll views. I will wait for any other suggestions otherwise i will follow your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same big problem 6 months ago with a 150 XIB app. In my case there was a bad MVC architecture which views and flows(controllers) are very dependent to each other in a lot of VC's so I had to configure all of the mekansm to make this UI compatible. If it is same with your case god helps you :) If not I'd suggest you to do Autolayouting when it is easy to implement and Autoresizing mask if there is complicated view hierarchy or animations.

Comment: If @FreeNickname were wrong, and it didn't require manual work, iOS would do it for you automatically. Layout constraints are one of those technologies Apple had to introduce to support hardware it wanted to sell, not one of those development-policy-driven coerced transitions.

Comment: @Krish, It's possible to add constraints for dynamic views in a scrollView. It's a bit more tricky than to add subviews to a normal view but it is possible. There are several articles on this topic (google "uiscrollview autolayout"). It can also be done in code. I hope, you'll succeed :)

Answer (score 3):

So I looked into this issue in everywhere and here is what I can suggest:

1.You can update every view to autolayout.
Pros: Every view of your app will be adaptive when you are done with it. In the next generation iPhone screens you won't get any problems in UI/UX side.
Cons: If view hierarchies or animations are complicated it could be a very hard and stressful process. And depends on views again it will be a longer process than it has to be.

2.You can update every view with AutoresizingMask and frame setting.
Pros: It can be a faster process than 1st one. You could handle complicated views much faster and have a iPhone 6 resolution transition easily.
Cons: It would be a riskier approach by means when a new iPhone size comes up you may need to update "ever view" of your app again.

3.You can mix Autolayout with Autoresizingmask and frame setting to optimize.
Pros: It would be slower than 2nd approach but not that risky at all and It can be much faster than 1st.
Cons: It will be a mixed fixes and you will need to update your views but not all of them.

From these 3 I would pick the 3rd one cause:
1. You will be supporting iPhone6 optimizely fast.
2. Most of your views will be autolayouted which would makes your app more adaptive. And there won't be so many views to deal with.

And for picking which way to do I'd first check view hierarchy then animations in that hierarchy. Hope that would help.

Comment: Good wrap up. I'd go with 1 since it's better in the long run. You might end up struggling with weird bugs if you go with 3 since you don't really know how autoresizing masks are translated into constraints by AutoLayout engine.